# How to use brower.get() in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, yeoman

I was using Protractor to test dropdown selection. The code is following:

```
var productCountry = element(by.model('main.productCountry1'));
productCountry.click();
var country = element.all(by.repeater('country in countries'));
country.get(5).click();
browser.sleep(500);
```

The error is:

```
Stack:
ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.81)`
```

I used code to see the data inside array [names]:

```
var names =element.all(by.repeater('country in countries').column('country.name'));
names.getText().then(function(txt){
    console.log(txt);
});
```

And the result shows the array looks like this:

```
['','', '', '', '', .....,'','Kenya','Kiribati',....,'','','','']
```

Only can get a part of elements, other elements are all empty. And I run several times，each time the empty parts are different. 
I used the first line code

```
browser.get('dist/#');
browser.get('app/index.html');
```

to get into the webpage. If I run the above second line code, there is a 'Not Found' shown on the website,and the error is:

```
Stack:
Error: Failed: Error while running testForAngular: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.81)
```

Does this caused the element empty? The example I saw online always used the second line `browser.get()`. Is there any one used the first method?

I found If changed the data in `$scope.country` in `scr/app/tab/main.controller`, when I run `gulp serve`, the options in selection changed, but when I run protractor and get from the `dist/#`,  the options are not changed. I guess it maybe caused the element empty. And I used yeoman to generate the files.

Comment: I have saved it. I used generated project by yeoman, and I need to use command 'gulp protractor' inside the command I used now ‘protractor protractor.conf.js' and now I can run the code with browser.get('/').
Second, I used getAttribute('value') inside getText(). Now the console results are not empty. 
But the new problem is even now I can get the value, when I run the code "country.get(5).click();" , the same error is still at there. But for another selection, it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the bower.get():

   I used the code like this "browser.get ('/'); " to instead of the two lines of code shown in the question. It will now show the index page.
2. For drop-down selection test:

   There are two things causing this error.

   ```
   var productCountry = element(by.id('countryName'));
   var country1 = element.all(by.repeater('country1 in countries'));
   productCountry.click();
   browser.sleep(500);
   var a = country1.get(2);
   a.click();
   browser.sleep(500);
   expect(a.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('Indonesia');
   ```

   Here is my code. One reason is after doing `productCountry.click()`, we need to let the browser sleep for a while to wait for the renderings to take effect.

   The other reason is I used two of the same repeater in my HTML file, and when I do the e2e test, the system can't distinguish which repeater I want attached to the element. So I changed the code from:

   ```
   var names =element.all(by.repeater('country in countries').column('country.name'));
   ```

   to

   ```
   var country1 = element.all(by.repeater('country1 in countries'));
   var country2 = element.all(by.repeater('country2 in countries'));
   ```

   And finally I can test two drop-down selections.